# Not able to update the model in `afterModel`

Tags: ember.js

In existing model, I am trying to add some values in it in the `afterModel` hook. But I am not finding in the model at all. How to do this?

here is my try :

```
afterModel:function(model,transition){

        var that = this;
        let trans = Ember.A();

        model.get('ccList').forEach(function(card,num){

            let cname = card.get('cardName');
            let numb = card.get('cardNum');

            card.get('cardtransactions').map(function(transaction){
//adding some values
                transaction.set('cardName', cname );
                transaction.set('cardNum', numb );
                transaction.set('selected', false );
                transaction.set('handlingFee', "" );

                trans.push( transaction );

            });
        });

        model.set('processedTrans',trans); //assigning back 

        console.log( JSON.stringify( model.get('processedTrans').get('firstObject'))); //but not getting here

    },
```

Comment: Try `trans.pushObject( transaction )` instead of `trans.push( transaction )`

Comment: What are you getting instead? What's the result of `console.log(model.get('processedTrans.length'),model.get('ccList.length'))` (and what do you expect it to be)?

Comment: @arne.b - I am trying to add some data to my model for feature requirements locally ( without disturb the store )

Comment: @kumkanillam I tried with `trans.pushObject( transaction )` no luck.. any other suggestion please?

Comment: Instead of `model.set`, you can try `Ember.set(model,'processedTrans',trans)`

Comment: @kumkanillam - I am just confused here, while I do : `console.log( JSON.stringify( model.get('processedTrans').get('firstObject') ));
  console.log( JSON.stringify( model.get('processedTrans').get('firstObject').get('cardName') ) );` first one hasn't have the data. But second console gives me the data

Comment: I think `Ember.set` will fix that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `model` object returned from the route's model hook is typically a raw object and `.get()` or `.set()` will throw an error. As mentioned in the comments the safe option is to use `Ember.get()` or `Ember.set()`, as they will support both a basic object and an Ember object.

```
/* Ember.get(model, key) provides a safe fallback if .get() is not available */
console.log(Ember.get(model, 'transactions'));

/* model.get(key) will throw an error */
console.log(model.get('transactions'));
```

Also, using `Ember.assign(model, { transactions, ...otherObjects })` can help simplify modifying the model in the `afterModel` or  `setupController` hooks.

Here is a rough EmberTwiddle to illustrate: [Modifying the Model in the AfterModel Hook](https://ember-twiddle.com/1aa5e7e25a9f6b7244a2f4309fe8f94c?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C)